# Time Series algorithm data source

Tags: sql, data-mining

I want to Predict My profits and i have Orders Table Contains the order date and value,
So i made this View:

```
   SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CAST(YEAR(OrderDate) AS CHAR(4)) + CAST(MONTH(OrderDate) AS varchar(2)) AS [Year/Month], SUM(TotalValue) AS Total
FROM         dbo.[Order]
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
ORDER BY MONTH(OrderDate)
```

and I created a new Mining Structure with Time Series Algorithm.

The Problem is that Algorithm doesn't recognize the Column [Year/Month] AS Date , So the predictable values was 201217 201218, for example.

What should I Do? Where exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, why don't you change column to be a count of months since day 0?  You can do this as:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT YEAR(OrderDate)*12 + MONTH(OrderDate) AS [Year/Month],
           SUM(TotalValue) AS Total
FROM         dbo.[Order]
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
ORDER BY MONTH(OrderDate);
```

To convert the values back to year and month:

```
year = floor((val - 1) / 12);
month = (val - 1) % 12 + 1;
```

The `-1`s are because January is counted as "1" and not "0".

Comment: Yes ! thank very much it works great, 
But I am a bit confused about the query for view , so if i want to view the month and year for this predictable value:
24163 i have to do : (24163/12) and round the result to get 2013 year then do 24163-24156 to get the 7 month ,,, ??! @Gordon Linoff